# Simple FTP client in Java can send the "list" command just once in passive mode

Tags: java, ftp, passive-mode

I still have some problems regarding the FTP session between my simple FTP client written in Java and a proFTP server.

I have connected to the server using passive mode. 
When I send the `list` command I get a response in ASCII of which files that are on the server. If I send the `list` command again, I don´t get any response. I cannot even get a response from other FTP commands that I send. It seems like the session "hangs".

Why does my simple java application stop getting replies when sending the `list` command a second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FTP, both active and passive modes supply a separate channel for transferring data. Whenever you want to send a command in passive mode that involves the sending of data (e.g. `list`) you must re-send the `PASV` to tell the server that you're about to perform an operation that involves the data connection. The server can then open up a new socket or continue to use the same one.

Here's an example session:

```
230 Login successful.
PASV
227 Entered Passive Mode (123,245,209,137,199,61)
LIST
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
LIST
425 Use PORT or PASV first.
PASV
227 Entered Passive Mode (123,245,209,137,202,198)
LIST
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
```

Notice that my second attempt to use `LIST` failed because I hadn't opened a data channel. Once I sent another `PASV`, I was able to use `LIST` again.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Didn´t know that I had to send PASV for each data channel. So a FTP client can operate on files in both passive and active mode simultaneously?

Comment: Sure, but some FTP servers don't support it. Usually it's possible though. PASV is pretty much the standard mode these days though, because most users are behind NAT routers.